# How to modify the jquery-ui dialog on bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, dialog, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have this following code for making a confirm dialog using jQuery UI:

```
function Help(section) {

$("#userpopup").remove();
$("body").append("<div id='userpopup' title='Help' style='display:none'></div>");

$('#userpopup').dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    width: 560,
    height: 500,
    buttons: {
        "OK": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            $("#userpopup").remove();
        }
    },
    open: function (event, ui) {
        $("#userpopup").html("<iframe width='100%' height='400' src='?help&section=" + section + "' frameborder='0' marginwidth='0' marginheight='0' allowtransparency='true'></iframe>");
    },
    beforeClose: function (event, ui) {
        $("#userpopup").html("");
    }
});


return false;
```

}

```
<input onClick="javascript:Help('templates')" type="button" class="btn" value="help">
```

How to change it to use Bootstrap Modals?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the standard Bootstrap modal markup..

```
<input id="btnHelp" type="button" class="btn" value="help">

<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
            <h3>Dialog</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
          <iframe src="" width="100%" height="400" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and then use modal 'show' event to dynamically set a different iframe src..

```
$('#helpBtn').click(function(){

    $('#myModal').on('show', function () {
        var frameSrc = "?help&section=templates"; // value can be passed from button
        $('iframe').attr("src",frameSrc);

    });
    $('#myModal').modal({show:true})
});
```

[**Demo of iFrame inside modal**](http://bootply.com/61676)

Answer (score 5):

Just to add on to @Kris Zhang's answer: The [Bootstrap Jquery Plugin](http://bootstrap.ourjs.com/) is really the answer to this. The function calls are the same as those of jquery dialog boxes but it automatically adds the divs around the dialog box in order to display the modal bootstrap style. Just add or steal the bootstrap library from the link above and you don't need to use iframes.

Comment: Nice hack until you realize things like events (open, close, etc) are not implemented. Maybe I'm missing something with the mess of Bootstrap and jQuery UI I've got.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at  [Bootstrap jQuery Plugin](http://bootstrap.ourjs.com/)

It's based on bootstrap 3.x

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.